# TeamSpeak 3 (Ts3Admin.class.php)

Tags: php

I have a problem with the function in PHP, and more precisely from ts3admin.class.php.

I have something written like that

```
    if($tsAdmin->getElement('success', $tsAdmin->connect())) {

        #login as serveradmin
        $tsAdmin->login($ts3_user, $ts3_pass);

        #select teamspeakserver
        $tsAdmin->selectServer($ts3_port);

        #set bot name
        $tsAdmin->setName($bot_nickname);

        #get clientlist

        while(true){
            sleep(1);

            $poke_time = date('H:30');
            $time = date('H:i');

            $msg = '[b][color=red]Przypomnienie[/color]!\n Aukcja jest za [color=#4779E3]5[/color] minut![/b]';

            #get clientlist
            $clients = $tsAdmin->clientList();

            foreach ($clients['data'] as $client){
                $clid = $client['clid'];

                if($time == $poke_time){
                    $tsAdmin->clientPoke($clid, $msg);
                    $i++;
                    sleep(11);
                    continue;
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Well, it works very well but at the time when he has to send messages he makes spam messages to many people even after 10 messages. Is it possible to somehow limit at a specified time only one message to all people on the server?

(I apologize for my English but I use google translate largely because I prefer Polish or German)

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Just write some code to achieve it ;)

Comment: Can you please guide me how to do it? I'm not good at PHP.

Comment: You could save the timestamp when the last message was send in the session or in the database, then compare that value before sending

Comment: I also thought about checking the number of people on the server and checking the number of sent messages. If the number of sent messages = the number of people goes to sleep for 5 minutes. But I do not know if it will work on a larger scale.

Comment: That does not sound good, as in this case one user could block the messaging system for all other users. And as you have required, only the "spamming" user should be blocked